# Is it harmful to Dim a variable more than once?

Tags: vbscript, wsh

This seems like an awfully basic question, but I still can't find an answer for it.

In VBScript, is there any harm in declaring the same scalar variable with the Dim statement more than once?

I'm working on some related projects and developing some code pieces I'd like to reuse.  However, I'm slightly concerned if there's a problem with using code that uses the same variable name twice, like so:

```
Dim i
for i = 1 to Count
    '* doin' somethin' here
next

Dim i
for i = 1 to UnrelatedOtherCount
    '* doin' somethin' different yo
next
```

It's not just iteration loop variables, either; I may have multiple places in a script where regexes are used.  If my script uses two sections of code being re-used, and each of them uses a "patternString" variable and starts by declaring the variables:

```
'* first section of code from the folder
Dim objPersonRegex, patternString
Set objPersonRegex = new RegExp
...

'* a completely different section of code
Dim objBuildingRegex, patternString
Set objBuildingRegex = new RegExp
```

My instinct is to say that it *shouldn't* be a problem, that Dim just creates a variable of the given name *if* it doesn't already exist, and if it does, just goes on because what it was told to do is done.  But is this actually the case?  In case it matters, these are scripts running on Windows Script Host.

(To clarify what I'm worried about, I'm *not* worried at all about the *value* of the variable getting clobbered.  If I need to retain the value of the variable, I'll save it in a different variable, one with a unique name.)

All my attempts to look up the answer myself have failed; they only return information about declaring more than one variable on a line, and using ReDim on arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Is it harmful to Dim a variable more than once?**

It is **impossible** to Dim a variable more than once. Neither **not** using `Option Explicit` nor (mis)**using** `On Error Resume Next` will get more than one Dim for the same variable (name) in the same compilation unit past the 'compiler'.

Answer (score 1):

Dim doesn't just create then re-create the variable.  It allocates a memory address for it.
So, assuming you are coding with OPTION EXPLICIT turned on, it won't let you even do that.

However...  What you're showing there as an example is not declaring the variable again.  Not the same way, at any rate.  That's not "dimmed".  It's just temporarily used and thrown away when it's done.  So, in that respect, you are doing it the right way.

If you were to create a new variable for every little thing that ran in a loop, when they don't interefere with each other, that becomes rather inefficient.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I guess I didn't express my concerns well (and after asking about the Dim statement, I forgot to put the Dim statements in my code! D'oh...)  I've revised my question to be more clear; do you feel the same answer is still applicable?

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, I would say that it is harmful, because it means you're coding with OPTION EXPLICIT OFF. **Don't do that**. Keep that option on.

For the second example, if they really are different sections of code, in different "namespaces" (as much as vbscript has that concept... different modules, I guess), you're probably okay. However, that code is similar enough that I would look into writing a method that does whatever it is you're about to do. Then just call the method.

However, if snippets in the second example are in the same module, it would be a problem... partly for the reason in my first paragraph, and partly because it can lead to a very specific kind of bug. Imagine you make a mistake in your code, where it's possible somehow in the last sample for `patternString` to go unassigned. If it's a completely new variable, that results in an error, such that we know something went wrong. With the current code, it's possible to run the code with old pattern. This is *worse* than an error, because it may cause the program to do things like make unexpected changes to a database, or show sensitive data to the wrong user.

Comment: Even with `Option Explicit` not specified VBScript throws an error here. So I'm guessing he not only has `Option Explicit` unspecified but also `On Error Resume Next`. The double whammy.

Comment: Is there a way that I can explicitly UN-declare the variable, then?  Say to WSH, in effect, "I no longer care about this variable at all, so even if you see me declare a variable with the same name, it's a brand-new variable"?

Comment: @afeldspar Yes. By using shorter methods and modules.